# Floor Function. Let x and y be rational numbers

Tags: discrete-mathematics

let x and y be rational numbers.

A. $\left \lfloor x \right \rfloor + \left \lfloor y \right \rfloor 
    = \left \lfloor x+y \right \rfloor$

B. $\left \lfloor x \right \rfloor + \left \lfloor y \right \rfloor 
    \le \left \lfloor x+y \right \rfloor$

C. $\left \lfloor x \right \rfloor + \left \lfloor y \right \rfloor 
    \ge \left \lfloor x+y \right \rfloor$

D. None of the above.

Can anyone please explain why the answer is B? Thank You!

Comment: Hint: think about $x=0.5$ and $y=1.5$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The fact that $\left\lfloor x\right \rfloor\leq x$ should be clear (let me know if it isn't). Now add this to the same inequality with $y$ to get:

$$\left\lfloor x\right \rfloor+\left\lfloor y\right \rfloor\leq x+y$$

Now, taking the floor of both sides does not change the left-hand side, and gives your answer.

Comment: This is the most elegant answer

Comment: Yes, please explain why ⌊x⌋≤x ?

Comment: @pkim the floor function of $x$ gives the greatest integer less than or equal to $x$. the key part there is *less than or equal to*. does that make sense?

Comment: Yes it is . Thank you!

Comment: @pkim, glad to hear it! when you get answers that are helpful, be sure to accept the one that helped the most and upvote all the ones you found helpful, too!

Answer (score 2):

Let $\left \lfloor x \right \rfloor = x_{0} + x_{1}, x_{0} \in \mathbb{Z}, 0\leq x_{1}<1$

Similarily we define $\left \lfloor  y\right \rfloor$

Then $\left \lfloor x \right \rfloor + \left \lfloor y \right \rfloor = x_{0} + y_{0}$

Now there are two cases to consider:

(i) $x_{1} + y_{1} < 1$

and

(ii) $x_{1} + y_{1} \geq 1$

Case (i):

$\left \lfloor x + y \right \rfloor = \left \lfloor x \right \rfloor + \left \lfloor y \right \rfloor = x_{0} + y_{0}$

Case (ii):

$\left \lfloor x + y \right \rfloor = x_{0} + y_{0} + 1 >  \left \lfloor x \right \rfloor + \left \lfloor y \right \rfloor $

Therefore $\forall x,y \in \mathbb{Q}$, $\left \lfloor x + y \right \rfloor \geq \left \lfloor x \right \rfloor + \left \lfloor y \right \rfloor$ as required

Comment: Thanks for your nice comment. I am also a fan of rigorously defined work, and I like yours as well.

Answer (score 1):

If $x$ and $y$ are rational (or real) numbers, then there must exist numbers $h$ and $k$ such that $0 \le h,k < 1$,  $x = \left \lfloor x \right \rfloor + h$, and  $y = \left \lfloor y \right \rfloor + k$.

So:
\begin{align}
   \left \lfloor x + y \right \rfloor
   &= \left \lfloor
         \left \lfloor x \right \rfloor + h +
         \left \lfloor y \right \rfloor + k
     \right \rfloor \\
   &= \left \lfloor x \right \rfloor +
      \left \lfloor y \right \rfloor 
      + \left \lfloor h+k \right \rfloor\\
   &\ge \left \lfloor x \right \rfloor +
      \left \lfloor y \right \rfloor \\
\end{align}

Comment: Your last inequality symbol is backwards, FYI.

Comment: I fixed it awhile.

Comment: @TheCount - The older I get, the more I do this.

Comment: I feel you. The other day I declared with confidence that $1/3+1/7=1$. I felt so dirty.

Answer (score 1):

For any $x$ then there is an integer $n$ so that $n \le x < n + 1$.  We call $n = [x]$.

so $[x] \le x < [x]+ 1; [y] \le y < [y] + 1$ so $[x]+ [y] \le x + y < [x] + [y] + 2$.

so there are two possibilities:

$[x] + [y] \le x + y < [x] + [y] + 1$ and so $[x+y] = [x]+ [y]$.  This will happen if $(x -[x]) + (y - [y]) < 1$.  e.g. $x = 2.3$ $y = 7.4$.

of $[x]+ [y] + 1 \le x+y < [x]+ [y]+ 1 + 1$ and $ [x+y] = [x]+[y] + 1$.  This will happen if $(x -[x]) + (y - [y]) \ge 1$. e.g $x = 2.5$ and $y=7.6$.

So $[x+y] = \{[x]+[y], [x]+[y]+1\}$.

In either case... $[x]+ [y] \le [x+y]$.